# How to change schema using Cloud Code beforeSave

Tags: parse-server

Given the following schema

```
{
 date: '2017-12-09',
 amount: 10.00,
 notify: true,
 isInvoiceSent: false
}
```

Suppose that I decided to drop the column isInvoiceSent, how can I use Cloud Code and beforeSave to drop that column?

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Invoice", function(request, response) {
  delete request.object.isInvoiceSent # <-- won't work
  response.success();
});
```

The main reason is because after disabling column creation I get:

`Permission denied for action addField on class Invoice`

Comment: I recommend using a server layer to manage object creation and stuff to avoid issues like this. I imagine just adding the column temporarily utnil clients are updated isn't an option because not all app users will update.  If you had used a cloud function to handle this functionality, you'd have a more seamless update.

Comment: @JakeT. like a PHP backend running in front of Parse? cheers

Comment: No, sorry, I mean right on your parse-server.  Say you have an Android and an iOS app. Instead of each individual app having business logic code that creates a new Invoice object and saves it to your parse-server, you have a cloud function called `createInvoice` which takes in necessary parameters, creates/saves the object, and returns it to the client.  This way, any changes to the business logic only need to be made in one place, without the need for any client updates by your users. Obviously can't catch everything, i.e. if you need new info. But it resolves many app updating issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ‘req.object.unset(“isInvoiceSent”)’

See: 
http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Object.html#unset For more infos!